# Is storing the connection pool in a singleton a bad practice?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I just read [this question and the answer claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863705/is-singleton-object-creates-per-session-or-per-server-startup-in-java#27863728):

> *"Lets assume db connection object is singleton in my application"*
>
> This is a must not. Your database connection **MUST NEVER BE** (yes, bolded and
> with capitals to make sure you and every reader never make this
> mistake) a singleton object. Your Connection con MUST NOT be part of a
> singleton to keep it open all the time. Instead, use a proper database
> connection pool that will take care of opening the necessary physical
> database connections and keep them alive through the live of your
> application.

We of course use a connection pool to take care of our, well, connections. Still, we store this pool in a singleton. How else would one ensure that it lives throughout the application? Ist his bad practice?

Comment: A connection pool might be one of the only valid use cases for a singleton pattern (which you usually want to avoid). I would be fine with it.

Comment: I think the answer means what you have done. Connections themselves should not be singletons, but CAN be managed by a singleton.

Comment: Like jr593, I think you just misread the answer. Your implementation of [Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) must not be designed as singleton, but your [Connection Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html) may be a singleton.

Comment: I too misread the text, I think is not a bad practice connections are a limited resource and are both expensive to initially create and then maintain over time. If not a singleton your system must still have access to a single instance of this pool but not a single instance to the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the quoted answer is mainly stating an **opinion**.

The one **fact** in that answer is about the "per classloader" aspect.

In other words: unless you are in a situation, where that "multiple classloaders" part comes in there are no *technical* reasons to not use a singleton.

Of course, the key element would be to implement a "correct" singleton; for example by using a Java enum for that.

Answer (score 1):

What the author of the quote says is that the connection must never be a singleton, not stored in a singleton. I can't imagine a connection as a singleton with status like "connected", "available", etc... Pools are made for this.

On an application I do the same thing as you, the connections are stored in a pool held by a singleton, so that any thread can use them.